# how to pass multiple tags to addTarget:action:forControlEvents?

Tags: ios, tags, ibaction

I know the code i have written is wrong. but i want something like this. How to do it?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
int totalcout = 0;
int passValue ;
for(int j=0; j<5; j++{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        totalcout++;
        if(totalcount >1){
          break;
        }else{
        passValue = i;
        }
    }
    button.tag = j;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


- (IBAction) button:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"tag numbers are  %d", sender.tag);

    detailViewController.mutableArray1 = [oneMutableArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    detailViewController.mutableArray2 = [twoMutableArray objectAtIndex:passValue];
}
```

I hope the question is clear.
Thank you in advance

Comment: what is `tag1` and `tag2`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with these two tags?

Comment: If you want to call the same IBAction method for different UIButton then you need to compare the tag in IBAction method. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: what do you want can you please share more clearly

Comment: Are you just trying to assign 2 tags to same button? why would you want to do that?

Comment: Is my question clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got your question.. you can't directly assign two tags to any UIView or any subclass directly. but you can achieve indirectly 
may this code helps to achieve your intension to  get two tags at the end

```
    #define First_Tag  100
    #define Second_Tag 200
  -(void)createButton
     {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.tag = ((First_Tag*10000)+30000)+(Second_Tag*10);
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      }

 - (void) button:(UIButton *)sender 
 {
   int intTag2 = ((sender.tag-30000)%10000)/10;
   int intTag1 = ((sender.tag-(intTag2*10))-30000)/10000;
   NSLog(@"tag numbers are  %d and %d", intTag1, intTag2);
  }
```

I've used several big numbers to encode the tag .. hope it solves your problem to assign two tags

Comment: I feel so foolish... It really is as simple and adding two desired tags, then subtracting one from the other to get the two tags again... Like the solution of swapping two integers without using a third variable